# Is it possible to add bootstrap classes to Infragistic web controls?

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, infragistics

I have picked up a small web app which has been built using Infragistics web controls. I am not familiar with Infragistics but am trying to improve the look of the app and have turned to what I know (bootstrap).

A simple example I am unable to add a bootstrap class to is as follows:

```
<ig:WebDataMenu ID="mLogInBtnMenu" runat="server" TabIndex="3" OnItemClick="LogInBtn_Click" Font-Bold="True" ActivateOnHover="False">
                        <GroupSettings Orientation="Horizontal" />
                        <Items>
                            <ig:DataMenuItem Key="mLogInBtn" Text="Log In" ImageUrl="~/Images/Image.ICO"></ig:DataMenuItem>
                        </Items>
                        <ClientEvents ItemClick="LogInButton_Click" />
        </ig:WebDataMenu>
```

This appear to be simply adding a login button to the screen. I want to add the following bootstrap class to the button:

```
class="btn btn-default"
```

I have tired adding the class to different parts of the code above but it causes the site to crash on load.

Does anyone know if adding bootstrap classes is even possible?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can cherck the following blog post on Infragistics website on how to style ASP.NEt controls with Bootstrap:

http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/alex_kartavov/archive/2014/04/21/asp-net-controls-and-bootstrap-styling.aspx